# Button Constraints Programmatically

Tags: swift, button, constraints, frame

I have gallery and when I click on picture I have objc function click onbutton, on this event I need to full screen image and get below the pic button.
I need to move the button but it's not working
I used frame for button but not worked and also not working button tap inside
when I wrote constraints in func onButton get error -> "Unable to activate constraint with anchors" there is any way to add the button in below the picture? [Button in top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mobBB.jpg)

```
@objc func onButton(sender: UIButton){

    let imageView = sender.currentImage!
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView)
    let imgFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    newImageView.frame = imgFrame
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .white
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    newImageView.addSubview(someButton)
}
@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}

private let someButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 24,
                          y: 100,
                          width: 100,
                          height: 54)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Make Profile Pic", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSomeButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.backgroundColor = .purple
    
    return button
}()
```

Comment: You have not added any constraints for `someButton`, add the constraints and it will be fine.

Comment: when I wrote constraints in func onButton get error -> "Unable to activate constraint with anchors"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Welcome to Stack overflow :)
secondly, Your question is very difficult to understand, Consider using a word processor to spell/grammar check your question before posting it here. We can help you faster if we understand what you're asking haha :P

thirdly. I believe your problem is in your declaration of `someButton`

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: 24,
                      y: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      height: 54)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

The `Y` coordinate here is only 100 from the top.

Considering the variety of iPhone screen sizes out there, I would recommend adopting Auto-layout in your code.

Xcode is not playing nice with me just now but you should be looking for something like this:

```
var button = UIButton() //declare your button
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //tell your button to use the constraints you set
view.addSubView(button) // add the button to the view

//this is the important part: here you are telling the centre of the button to be horizontally centre in the view
button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true 

//with this line you are telling the button to position itself vertically 100 from the bottom of the view. you can change the number to whatever suits your needs
button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
```

You would also want to set `button.widthAnchor` and `button.heightAnchor` as these would not be set in the frame any longer.

***important tips***

In my (admittedly limited) experience, You should ensure you add the button the view before applying the constraints.

your app might experience some layout bugs if you are using both frames and constraints. I would recommend that now is a good time to change any frames on this view to use constraints instead :)

I hope this example works, with my Xcode deciding to just give up on me I've had to write this entirely from memory. lemme know how you get on :P

Comment: Not sure if `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` should be true or false. I put false in my answer, If it still doesn't work, try true :)

Answer (score 0):

hey may be this code will help you.

```
 button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.width/2,
                          y: self.view.bounds.height,
                          width: 100,
                          height: 54)
```

just replace your that line here we are getting view height and width with this code **self.view.bounds.height**

sorry if i'm on wrong track.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the constraints and add the button in the view and not in imageView, I have not seen your imageView constraints, so I hope imageView is not constrained to top and bottom of the entire view. Add the button in the view, give it constraints and as you are using constraints, you can skip the `button.frame` and add `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor`. At last activate them and keep `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` as `false`.

```
    @objc private func onButton(sender: UIButton){

    let imageView = sender.currentImage!
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView)
    newImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .white
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap) 

    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)

    // New Image View Constraints 

    newImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: .zero).isActive = true
```

newImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: .zero).isActive = true
newImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: .zero).isActive = true
newImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:600).isActive = true // Adjust according to your needs
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

```
    //Add In View & SomeButton Constraints

    view.addSubview(someButton)
     someButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        someButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        someButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        someButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: newImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
}

private lazy var someButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Make Profile Pic", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSomeButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.backgroundColor = .purple
    
    return button
}()
```

Also, it will be better if you can add proper names. Also, for long term you should create an `extension` to setup your `constraints` with `padding`.

P.S.: I checked your newImageView constraints that was Given to the full frame, I've updated the constraint for the same.